# 3rd declension accusative plurals

Tags: grammar-choice, orthography

I am being driven round the bend by people’s insistence on “playing Horace on original instruments” and I need some way out of the morass.

At school the 3rd declension accusative plural ending was *-es* and that was that. Rudyard Kipling uses this - *maerentes amicos* and so on - which I suppose shows that I am a contemporary of Kipling. I need to de-obsolesce, because I am getting tired of asking “what is this genitive singular doing in *maerentis amicos*?”.

Gildersleeve and Lodge say for vowel stems in *i* (**57.5**) that “*-is* is found frequently in the classical period along with the later termination *-es*, which supplants *-is* wholly in the early empire”. They also add that polysyllabic stems in *nt* are in a very real sense stems in *i* (**54** though their wording is more Victorian than mine).

Now, given that one has to face texts which have intruded the loathsome *-is*, what are the rules?

My first guess was that one could say simply “anything that has a genitive plural in *-ium* will have its accusative plural written as *-is*.

Is this a complete and sufficient rule?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Unfortunately, there doesn't seem to be any rule that is both simple and complete. This might be the reason why so many modern editions normalize spellings by replacing accusative plural *-īs* with *-ēs* (unless the word has an accusative singular in *-im*).

Your suggestion that accusative plural *-īs* is possible if the word has a genitive plural ending in *-ium* is a good rule of thumb, but has exceptions.
As per the answer I posted in reply to the prior question [Constantis vs. constantes et similia](https://latin.stackexchange.com/q/4153/9), Allen and Greenough [§77](http://dcc.dickinson.edu/grammar/latin/3rd-declension-summary-i-stem-forms), [§117 and §118](http://dcc.dickinson.edu/grammar/latin/3rd-declension-adjectives-classification-and-paradigms) have some information on the use of this ending (although some of what this source says about etymology is out of date).

I think that some words may have an attested accusative plural in *-īs* but no attested genitive plural in *-ium.* For example, comparative adjectives generally are inflected as consonant stems (an exception to the general tendency for Latin third-declension adjectives to be i-stems), but the non-neuter accusative plural of comparatives is sometimes found ending in *-ōrīs* (as in the example of [*peioris* asked about in this question](https://latin.stackexchange.com/questions/17846/)). I haven't seen a corresponding genitive plural *peiōrium* used anywhere in ancient texts.